# How to filter table with conditions stored as parameters in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, filter, conditional-statements

I want to use parameters stored in tableA to filter tableB.

Here is my tableA with parameters:

[image: parameterstable]

I want to filter tableB with more or less such a query:

```
WITH A AS 
    (SELECT 
         [FilterType]
        ,[MaxID]
    FROM TableA
    WHERE [FilterType]=1
    )

SELECT * FROM TableB B
WHERE B.ID>A.MaxID
```

I want to get all the records from TableB where B.ID is larger than MaxID chosen from TableA for a FilterType 1. How to do it? Speaking more generally, how to get a parameter from table and use this parameter for query?

Comment: Tables don't have parameters, they have values. Seems like this is a pretty straight forward join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a lot of detail here but something like this?

```
select b.Columns
from TableB b
join TableA a on a.MaxID <= b.ID
where a.FilterType = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT B.*
FROM TableB AS B
JOIN TableA AS A ON B.ID > A.MaxID
WHERE A.FilterType = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  WITH A AS 
    (SELECT 
         [FilterType]
        ,[MaxID]
    FROM TableA
    WHERE [FilterType]=1
    )
SELECT B.* FROM TableB B,A
WHERE B.ID>A.MaxID
```